# rails model validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to go through all my models and make sure relationships are specified on both sides? Such as if there as a Client who has_many courses, then course must have a belongs_to client

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build into rails? No...

But if you need an association which isn't there, something in your application is going to break...

You might want to look at [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) for testing